# Pointer issues when using sqlite in an objective-c program

Tags: c, objective-c, sqlite, pointers, warnings

When i try to compile this as part of an objective-c program it gives the warning:
 `warning: passing argument 1 of 'sqlite3_close' from incompatible pointer type`

```
sqlite3 *db;
sqlite3_open("~/Documents/testdb.sqlite", &db);
/*stuff*/
sqlite3_close(&db);
```

An almost identical error is given with nearly any other function call that uses `&db`.

Comment: Ok, I really need to dig out that copy of the K&R book and actually *learn* to use pointers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you need the second `&`...  If this is anything like plain c, you just want to call `sqlite3_close(db);`  (Thereby passing it the pointer itself, rather than the address of the pointer.)  The `sqlite3_open` call would, I believe, be left as is.

Comment: Objective-C is a strict superset of C.

Answer (score 2):

`sqlite3_close` requires a `sqlite3*`, not a `sqlite3**`. So drop the ampersand and it should compile.

Answer (score 1):

You should just pass in the pointer, not a reference to it:

```
sqlite3_close(db);
```